# Use methods of parent class A from parent class B

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, superclass

I have a class A:

```
class A(object):
   def pprint(x):
       print(x)
```

Then I have a class B:

```
class B(object):
    def pprint(x):
        x += 1
        # find a way to call A.pprint(x)
```

Then I have a child class:

```
class Child(B, A):
    pass
```

Which should be used:

```
child = Child()
child.pprint(1)
>>> 2
```

I can make changes to B but not to A. I cannot refer to A directly in B. B will never be instantiated directly, always via children class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the explanation - what you need is not `super()` you need something like `sibling_super()` to find the next class in the multiple inheritance chain. You can poll Python's MRO for that, for example:

```
class A(object):

    def pprint(self, x):  # just to make it valid, assuming it is valid in the real code
        print(x)

class B(object):

    @staticmethod
    def sibling_super(cls, instance):
        mro = instance.__class__.mro()
        return mro[mro.index(cls) + 1]

    def pprint(self, x):
        x += 1
        self.sibling_super(B, self).pprint(self, x)

class Child(B, A):
    pass

child = Child()
child.pprint(1)  # 2
```

Comment: Neither option would work in my case. I simplified the problem to make it more presentable, but in the real case I have many other classes like Class A, all with the same methods. So you can have `Child(B, A)` but also `AnotherChild(B, D)` or `YetAnotherChild(B, E)`. For the same reason, the second option you presented is also not feasible.

Comment: @EdgardDerby - so you don't know what's the second class name you use in your multiple inheritance?

Comment: correct. The only thing I know is that the class that will co-parent with `Class B` has a known interface (in the example above, all classes are bound to have a method `pprint()`). This is why I cannot directly refer `Class A` within `Class B`.

Comment: @EdgardDerby - explore the MRO in that case. You might want to add some guards, tho - e.g. whether there really is your class in the MRO. Check the update above.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options for accessing the A method from the B class without having B inherit from A.

First, you could create a staticmethod and call it from B.

```
class A(object):
   @staticmethod
   def pprint(x):
       print(x)

class B(object):
    def pprint(self, x):
        print(x + 1)
        A.pprint(x)
```

Or you could inherit A in B like this:

```
class A(object):
    def pprint(self, x):
        print(x)

class B(A):
    def pprint(self, x):
        print(x + 1)
        super(B, self).pprint(x)
```

Then for your `Child` class only inherit from B:

```
class Child(B):
    pass


>>> c = Child()
>>> c.pprint(1)
2
1
```

OK, newest solution.

```
import inspect

class C(B, A):
    def pprint(self, x):
        a_class = inspect.getmro(Child)[-2]
        a_class.pprint(self, x)
```

Since `object` will be the last result in `inspect.getmro(Child)` we skip that one to get the one before the last one, which is `A`. We then call that class's `pprint` method. You could also, to be more sure, if you know the `__name__` of the class you want to call, iterate over the results from `inspect.getmro(Child)` and find the one that you want.

Comment: As I mentioned below, neither option would work. In the post I set up two constrains: (a) I cannot modify `Class A` and (b) I cannot, in any way, refer directly to `Class A` in `Class B`. I can only use super(), __class__, __bases__, etc.

Comment: @EdgardDerby I'm not sure I understand why the second option I provided won't work since you're not directly modifying A. You're not modifying it at all. You're doing exactly what you just said you want to do. Call the `super()` function from `B`.

Comment: I mentioned two constraints: the second constraint is that you **cannot** refer to `Class A` in `Class B` in any way, which includes having B inherit directly from A. I provided additional details about the specific case below @zwer's answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I wasn't considering the inheritance directly referring to the class.

Comment: @EdgardDerby Can you modify `Child`? If so I've provided another solution where you can access `A`'s pprint method from `Child`